# libGDX as a "launcher" app

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx

I have made a light weight java web-server serving html files and static content (made with pure java library nanohttpd), i have successfully made a javaFX launcher window that has a single button, clicking button simply runs the server in the background and opens the localhost URL in Android/PC browser (I was unsuccessful in making an IOS version using javaFX)

I am thinking of using libGDX as "launcher window" because of IOS support and access to mobile specific hardware like SMS/GPS which javaFX don't have.
I am targeting IOS/Android/PC, I'd like to ask libGDX developers how possible is this given my target platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you can**

There's a catch though, you may have to build the UI the game dev way

I've made a game or two using it and had rather steep learning curve in the beginning to get a hold on to how it worked. For example you'll have to provide the images for button, background and also, the pressed view of the button... like that. But your app is not a game. So you won't have to worry that much.

Once you learned how to place them in the screen successfully, there is not much to worry about because the API provides everything you need to carry on from there.

Also I found enough resources/tutorials online enough to make a game from ground up. So you'll definitely can.

And there's very little to worry about your multi-platform problem.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, I'm guessing if i use "pure-java" libraries and refrain from using JNI everything should go well

Comment: Yes, And I don't see why you would need JNI.